# Can I set the factor/speed of i++ and i--?

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, operators

`i++` or `i--` adds or deducts the value of `i` by 1 each time it is executed.

Is there a way to change the factor of adding or deducting of `i++` and `i--` to, for example, 5?

Meaning that each time `i++` or `i--` is executed, it adds or deducts its value by 5 instead of only 1.

For example:

```
var i = 0;  
i++;
```

Instead of having output of `1, 2, 3, 4...`, can it get an output of `5, 10, 15, 20...` or `6, 12, 18, 24...`?

Comment: You can't overload operators in javascript. You'll just need to write a couple of extra characters to achieve this.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It would make the code very confusing to maintain. What's wrong with saying `i += factor` where `factor` can be set to whatever you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;  
i = i + 5;

or

i += 5;
```

It will increment i by value 5

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are looking something like this

```
var dynamVar = 5;

for(i=0;i<100;i=i+dynamVar){
document.write('<pre>'+i+'</pre>')
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/0e6upqj7/)